# How Dynamically Created Button Target Individual Element

Tags: javascript

I am under the impression if we target an element by element name of class name it will be applicable to all elements or elements with that class name. But in the following code when I clicked a button it will only change the innerHTML of the nearest span element even though I have add event listener by selecting just button element. Please clarify. Thanks.

```js
const myArray = [0, 1, 2];

let myContainer = document.querySelector('.container');

const newArray = myArray.map((item) => {
    let newArticle = document.createElement('article');
    const myHTML = `<article>
                    <span></span>
                    <button>Click ${item}</button>
                    </article>
    `;
    newArticle.innerHTML = myHTML;

    let myBtn = newArticle.querySelector('button');

    myBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        newArticle.querySelector('span').innerHTML = 'clicked';
    })

    return newArticle;
});

newArray.forEach((item) => {
    myContainer.appendChild(item);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
<section>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.container');` returns an srray. So the first element mathing the class would be `document.getElementByClassName("container")[0]` or `document.querySelectorAll('.container')[0]`. Try using the Array forEach method on this. Please note I used `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: You're only selecting the closes `span` because you looking for a `span` inside article here: `newArticle.querySelector('span')`. Changing it to `document.querySelector('span')` would then find all `span` elements.

Comment: @MasterMind `querySelectorAll` returns an array, not `querySelector` :)

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro right. Sory for that.

Comment: Why are you creating an `article` within an `article`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let myBtn = newArticle.querySelector('button');
```

returns the FIRST button in newArticle

```
let myBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

returns ALL buttons in document

You can tell us what you expect by clicking on each one button?